# Mojave won't show disk in Disk Utility

Tags: time-machine, mojave

I purchased a new disk to use as a Time Machine backup.

diskutil list shows it as:-

```
/dev/disk4 (external, physical):
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *2.0 TB     disk4
1:               Windows_NTFS                         2.0 TB     disk4s1
```

But is does not appear in Disk Utility or in Finder.

How should I go about formatting it?

Last time I did something similar I was prompted if I wanted to use it as Time Machine

Answer (score 1):

I used `gparted` on a Linux machine (Raspberry Pi) to delete the partition table.

Disk Utility then recognised it, and I could create a GPT partition table.

Added to Time Machine and it seems to be working (150GB to go) .